# Detecting ill formed strings and comments in flex

Tags: flex-lexer, lex, lexical-analysis

I am just learning flex and I have written a flex program to detect a given word is verb or not. I will take input from a text file.I want to improve the code. I want to detect if there is any ill formed or unfinished string in the code.Unfinished means it starts using the start symbol (" " or /* ) but doesn't have any ending one and ill formed means,for example ( "I am" a boy") or (/* this is a */ comment */) like these ones. I want to detect them in my code. How will I do that? My sample code is as follows:

```
%%

[\t]+

is   |

am   |

are  |

was  |

were {printf("%s: is a verb",yytext);}

[a-zA-Z]+ {printf("%s: is a verb",yytext);}

["][^"]*["] {printf("'%s': is a string\n", yytext); }

. |\n

%%

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){    
    yyin = fopen(argv[1], "r");    
    yylex();         
    fclose(yyin);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is  similar in solution to the [multi-line comment problem answered previously.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29991073/checking-unfinished-comments-in-flex). I quote from that:

> The [flex manual section on using `<<EOF>>`](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/EOF.html) is quite
>   helpful as it has exactly your case as an example, and their code can
>   also be copied verbatim into your flex program.
>
> As it explains, when using `<<EOF>>` you cannot place it in a normal
>   *regular expression* pattern. It can only be proceeded by a the name of a state. In your code you are using a state to indicate you are
>   inside a string. This state is called `STRING_MULTI`. All you have
>   to do is put that in front of the `<<EOF>>` marker and give  it an
>   action to do.
>
> The special action function `yyterminate()` tells flex that you have
>   recognised the `<<EOF>>` and that it marks the end-of-input for your
>   program.

Combining the stings and comments into one flex program gives you:

```
%option noyywrap
%x COMMENT_MULTI STRING_MULTI


%%

[\n\t\r ]+ { 
  /* ignore whitespace */ }


<INITIAL>"/*" { 
  /* begin of multi-line comment */
  yymore();
  BEGIN(COMMENT_MULTI); 
}

<INITIAL>["] { yymore(); BEGIN(STRING_MULTI);}

<STRING_MULTI>[^"]+ {yymore(); }

<STRING_MULTI>["]    {printf("String was : %s\n",yytext); BEGIN(INITIAL); }

<STRING_MULTI><<EOF>> {printf("Unterminated String: %s\n",yytext); yyterminate();}

<COMMENT_MULTI>"*/" { 
  /* end of multi-line comment */
  printf("'%s': was a multi-line comment\n", yytext);
  BEGIN(INITIAL); 
}

<COMMENT_MULTI>. { 
  yymore();
} 

<COMMENT_MULTI>\n { 
  yymore();
} 

<COMMENT_MULTI><<EOF>> {printf("Unterminated Comment: %s\n", yytext); yyterminate();}

%%

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){    
  yylex();         
}
```